# How to install python modules from one server to another server in offline mode

Tags: python

I need an idea on how to move or to install the python modules which is installed on one server to another server.

Below are the options i thought of

1. Download the modules from internet and copy them to server B and install it.

from the above option our admins are not ready to install as it will be downloaded from internet and it's not safe to install these packages.

2. Copy the already existing modules from server A and move to server B and install it.

From the above option iam not able to find all the modules in .tar.gz or Bz2 packages. Like for example pandas , iam not able to find the .gz or .bz2 packages on server A. Is there a way that i can find these packages and copy or move these files from server A to server B?

Comment: Where do admins think modules come from if not the Internet?

Comment: If these are python modules, they probably already come with python (in which case you can use a simple `import`) or they can be installed with `pip`. No need to transfer anything from server to server.

Comment: agreed all the modules come from internet, we already had a server where all the necessary modules are installed need to e move to other server and installed in offline mode ( with out internet connection) as the other server has firewall it will not allow external connections.